# How do I figure out where wrong local dns results are coming from?

Tags: debian, networking, dns, dig

I'm running mint Mate 17.2.

When I use dig, for a certain specific domain name, the resolved IP "answer" is wrong, and the answer server is `127.0.0.1`.

Trying to access this domain from my local computer via ssh, a web browser, etc also resolves to the wrong IP.

DNS lookup using online tools or other computers works correctly.

Something on the local machine is intercepting the request and returning a wrong cached result. I have looked at various caching programs, but I don't think I have any installed or configured any.

The IP address being returned is the old IP and the master DNS records were changed over a year ago.

How do I determine what program is intercepting DNS locally and disable it so I can have this domain resolve correctly on my computer?

**/etc/resolv.conf:**

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.1.1
```

Comment: Add the contents of `/etc/resolv.conf`.  Also, are you certain that you're not running a local DNS server such as `bind`?

Comment: I added resolv.conf above. `bind` or `bind9` is not in /etc/init.d so I assume it's not installed.

Comment: @DopeGhoti must be resolvconf or dnsmasq.

Comment: `resolvconf` is in init.d. `dnsmasq` is not installed. Still not sure where resolvconf is getting it's info from though, since there's nothing set in `resolv.conf` or `/etc/hosts`.

Comment: what is the output of `sudo netstat -anlp | grep :53`?

Comment: Please add what kind of domains are giving you trouble. .local by change? Also check for avahi* packages, please.

Comment: There are `avahi-daemon` entries in `netstat -anlp | grep :53`. The domain is a publicly registered .com domain with public dns records. The domain resolve properly on other computers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Resolvconf is pointing it out to a local software running in port 53 in the local machine.

To find it out which one:

```
sudo netstat -anlp | grep :53
```

As we have found out, it is the avahi  daemon.

To trace DNS resolution, also following command is useful:

```
dig +trace www.cnn.com
```

If you want to control your DNS setting yourself, specially in server cases (I have notice you said Mint), I would recommend doing away with resolvconf

You can uninstall it with:

```
dpkg --purge resolvconf
```

Then, if you got the IP via DHCP leave it as it is, otherwise fill in your DNS servers in /etc/resolv.conf.

If you are not also interested in mDNS resolution or in a corporate network, I recommend uninstalling avahi.

In desktop settings, it maybe advisable either to reboot or restart all services. I would at least restart networking with `service networking restart`.

> The Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD daemon implements Apple's Zeroconf architecture
>   (also known as "Rendezvous" or "Bonjour"). The daemon registers local
>   IP addresses and static services using mDNS/DNS-SD and provides two
>   IPC APIs for local programs to make use of the mDNS record cache the
>   avahi-daemon maintains.

In a work setting, it maybe also be interesting following up at the network level servers/workstations which are announcing mDNS records, and if they are strictly necessary. I would bet some lost host file or some old server setting is propagating your old IP address via mDNS.

You may also listen in the local network mDNS packets with:

```
sudo tcpdump -n udp port 5353
```

From [mDNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_DNS)

> The multicast Domain Name System (mDNS) resolves host names to IP
>   addresses within small networks that do not include a local name
>   server. It is a zero-configuration service, using essentially the same
>   programming interfaces, packet formats and operating semantics as the
>   unicast Domain Name System (DNS). Although Stuart Cheshire designed
>   mDNS to be stand-alone capable, it can work in concert with unicast
>   DNS servers.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The erroneous entry was coming from the router which has it's own DNS server built in. Once I disabled resolvconf on my computer, dig showed the router's IP, not the loopback IP as the source of the bad records. It's a shame resolvconf hides the true source of the records from dig.

Comment: I do not allow neither resolvconf nor avahi services in my servers at work and my Linux router at home. Usually soho router DNS services are slow...better have a dedicated Linux DNS server/cache.

Comment: As for the router, the old entry was put there by hand, right?

Comment: Yes, it was manually added a long time ago.

Comment: But with Ubuntu/Mint, `dpkg --purge resolvconf` tells you `ubuntu-minimal depends on resolvconf.`

Comment: Ubuntu or Mint?  Apparently it solved the OP problem. At least in Debian I have been able to do it for years (in Debian 9 now). Would it be worth filing a bug with Ubuntu?